# Create geometries from data-only tables using virtual layers

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, virtual-layer

In QGIS 3.18, I have two data-only layers (csv) - the table `coordinates` containing lat/lon values, the table `data` containing attribute data. Both tables have a common unique id: 1 (data) : n (coordinates). I now want to visualize the data on the map.

What I tried: I made a table join to add the coordinates to the `data` table - that works. Than I created a virtual layer with this query:

```
select d.field_1, d.field_2, d.field_3, d.field_4, d.field_5,d.field_6, d.coordinates_lat, d.coordinates_lon, make_point(d.coordinates_lon, d.coordinates_lat) as geometry
from data as d
```

This works fine.

Now I would like to do table join in the virtual layer as well. How is the correct syntax to achieve that?

*Screenshot: creating point geometries from table join:*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general form of the query to join the tables would be something like:

```
    SELECT d.field_1, d.field_2, d.field_3, d.field_4, d.field_5,d.field_6,
           c.Lat, c.lon, make_point(c.lon, c.lat) as geometry
    FROM data AS d 
    JOIN coordinates AS c
    ON d.id = c.id
```

I'm not sure what the name of the common unique id is - in the query above I used "id" `ON d.id = c.id` you may need to change that to suit.

You said there is 1 to n relationship with `data` being the one and `coordinates` the many.  So you would end up with multiple objects with the same id, I'm wondering if this will cause any issues for displaying/selecting/info-ing on the map. If it proves to be an issue you could use the sqlite row_number function to add a unique number for each row - add this to the field list in the select: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.field_1) as uid`

Comment: This works, however QGIS gets quite slow. So probably for larger tables still the two-step approach (first table join, than virtual layer) is more practicable.

Comment: Yeah, its a shame the virtual layers are cool but sometimes not practical, especially with joins it seems. I wonder if  `SELECT d.field_1, d.field_2, d.field_3, d.field_4, d.field_5,d.field_6,
               (SELECT make_point(lon, lat) FROM coordinates  WHERE id = d.id) as geometry
        FROM data AS d`  would be faster/slower/the same?  This query would only make sense if there was a single matching `coordinate` row for each `data` row - I think is the case because you   > made a table join to add the coordinates to the data table

Comment: No, unfortunately the second query is not significantly faster. There are several points in the same location, so each coordinate is used multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for humouring me by taking the time to try. :)